# Cookies without authentication ? (and cookie value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails app with Devise and was checking on front end if my Rails app was implementing cookies in order to comply with European rules regarding cookies.

I was a bit surprised as my Rails app actually add cookies to the client even without any Devise authentication ...

The cookie has name `_myapp_session`

Actually it is a good thing as I could add the cookie law information inside this cookie (user gets to see the cookie law warning only once)

...Yet each time I reload the root page in my browser the cookie is renewed.. So it doesn't actually look like a session cookie.

Is there a wrong setup in my initializer or can someone help me fix this ? (or maybe this is completely normal)

**EDIT** : Maybe my mistake : the cookie value is changing on every page yet the session creation time is not changing so I guess it is still valid to consider it a session cookie. I will search the web for a thorough explanation on cookies as the cookie value changing all the time is probably a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are created by default in Rails Application.
Also, you're probably using Rememberable module in Devise which uses cookies.
Devise 'refreshes' csrf token after each request. Hence why it changes.

Did you try to look inside cookie and see what it contains?

Here's how you might do it (old rails version):
https://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/03/19/cookies-on-rails.html

Comment: Seems to fail in Rails 5. I get an error when trying to decrypt unescaped_content with built encryptor based on secret_key_base. I will try to parse the hash of the cookie in a view and see what it contains .. But as the value changes all the time, and user is not authenticated, it maybe picks a time or something..

Comment: Ok interesting I get `["session_id", "f518948ec0e922ec44b9bf28d1xxxxxx"] ["flash", {"discard"=>[], "flashes"=>{"notice"=>"Déconnecté."}}] ["professionnel_return_to", "/"] ["_csrf_token", "VeXWfBNs6KYV6CmEYpsPSLeBtbf8i2jxC+tqBGxxxxxx"] ` some flashes from Devise and a signout path to model professionnel from Devise also. When I log in I can indeed see the Devise model record ID. When i reload page the cookie value changes but the Session ID and the CSRF token value don't change.. pretty strange

Comment: I guess the session cookie content can remain same but the cookie value change because of encryption .. kind of salted.. Well anyway I will add a Cookie Law boolean in order to manage display of Cookie law warning to this session cookie and I should be fine ...

Comment: Devise 'refreshes' `_csrf_token` after each request. Hence why it changes. Updated answer